# Microsoft Exchange: add **for foouser** to received-line

Tags: exchange, smtp-headers

Some mail servers tell me the envelope recipient in the `Received` header.

In this example the third headers shows `needle@vooconto.de`.

```
Received: from mail.example.com (..) by visexchange01.vooconto.intern
 (..) with Microsoft SMTP Server (TLS) id ..;
 Fri, 11 Mar 2016 11:39:48 +0100
Received: from smtprelay02.foogateway.de (unknown [..]) by
 mail.example.com with smtp    (TLS:
 TLSv1/SSLv3,256bits,ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384)    id
 5649_10e1_8eacfe41_514f_4bdf_b429_dcd43b649b9e;    Fri, 11 Mar 2016 11:39:45
 +0100
Received: from [..] (helo=lkwsmtp.itfoo.de)   by
 smtprelay02.foogateway.de with esmtpa (Exim 4.84)  (envelope-from
 <Matthias.Rischer@example.com>)   id 1aeKTu-0000OS-LW for
 needle@vooconto.de; Fri, 11 Mar 2016 11:39:45 +0100
```

How can I configure the Microsoft SMTP Server to add "for needle@vooconto.de" to the received line?

**Goal**

I have a mailbox which receives mails for several addresses. I want to group the mails according their original (envelope) to-header.